# HTTP Basic Auth pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have API with HTTP Basic Auth. If I run curl `my_url --user login:pass` 
I get:

```
users":"my_url/users/","user":"my_url/user/","platforms":"my_url/platforms/","adverts":"my_url/adverts/","categories":"my_url/categories/"}
```

I created login form in html with two input fields (login and pass) and I would like to authorised in my API, if login and pass correct then alert Success and else Wrong.

I have something like this :

```
function login()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'my_url';
    http.open("get", url, true, username, password);
    http.send();
    console.log(http.status + " i " + http.responseText);
    if (http.status == 200) {
        alert("Success");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work.
API and my website is on the same machine (with the same IP address).

Comment: Hopefully you mean JavaScript on server side, correct?

Comment: I doubt that `document.getElementById("login")`

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is async. You wont get immediate status and responseText. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: Robert, I want to use pure JS, without Node. Is it possible?